# Encrypt and decrypt a string of text with RSA and DES3 key

Tags: linux, public-key-encryption

I am using the Linux command line, I have created a Private Key using the following command:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.pem 2048
```

I have extracted the public key from the private key like so:

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -out public.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

I want to use the public key to encrypt a string of text, lets say "foo bar", and then decrypt this string again.

How do I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public.pem -pubin -in unencrypted_file.txt -out encrypted_file.ssl
```

See more at [devco](http://www.devco.net/archives/2006/02/13/public_-_private_key_encryption_using_openssl.php).